# Kotlin Android extension - synthetic properties are not available inside support fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, androidx

I have an Android project with such dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

The project is being written in Kotlin with the usage of synthetic properties for view elements. Fragment implementations in my project extend Fragment from package android.support.v4.app. I've met with a problem that inside my fragments I can't access to my views through synthetics - I'm getting message like this:

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable
>   because 
>       of receiver type mismatch: public val Activity.detailButton: Button! defined 
>       in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome public val 
>       Dialog.detailButton: Button! defined in 
>       kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome public val android.app.Fragment.detailButton: Button! defined in
>   kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome public val
>   androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.detailButton: Button! defined in
>   kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome public val
>   LayoutContainer.detailButton: Button! defined in
>   kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome

The only way to fix the problem is to extend fragment from androidx.fragment but I need fragments only from Support Libraries! In other parts of project (for example ViewHolder with LayoutContainer) synthetic property feature works fine. So I need a help to resolve this issue.

Recently, in Android Studio I've made a migration to AndroidX with "Refactor-Migrate to AndroidX" feature. But it was made on backuped project. Maybe it could influence on my situation